# Dynamic Facebook Like URLs with Javascript- displaying but not posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have multiple blocks of content on my page that users can open and explore. Within these blocks is a Like button relevant to each block. Each Like button widget has a URL that is dynamically generated when the blocks of content are opened, e.g.

```
$('.socialMedia').append("<div class='fb-like' data-href='"+likeUrl+"' data-send='true' data-width='250' data-show-faces='false' data-colorscheme='dark'></div>");
```

The Like URL is an address in the format of http://url.com/like-shY76739jj.php - when accessed such URLs redirect to a query-string URL via some .htaccess magic. However, this is probably irrelevant for my problem...

The issue is is that the dynamic URL generated through Javascript does not send through to Facebook. It generates correctly in my source code (inspecting the Like Button elements shows that the correct URL is in the widget href attribute), and appears correctly in the Like button pop-up window (straight after the button is clicked, when the user has the choice to enter an additional message), but when I check the story on Facebook the URL is incorrect - specifically it comes back as:

http://url.com/like-.php - the dynamic ID I am slotting in to my likeURL variable is not translating from the page into the Facebook story. I have no idea why.

I am using the `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('socialMedia'));` code already, but this is not solving the issue.

**TL:DR** Dynamic URLs used in Facebook Like buttons display correctly within the widget, but not in the generated Facebook story.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Each your `http://url.com/like-[...]` page should has OpenGraph tags - og:title, og:image etc. For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your section - your website" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL_OF_PAGE" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://url.com/images/section1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description"/>
```

You can test your urls using OpenGraph Debugger - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks for helping but that isn't the issue I don't think. The URLs all have the meta tags on them just fine (they are generated server side with PHP), but it's just that these URLs aren't coming up as the links in the Facebook Like stories. They appear in the like widget code and stuff, but don't go through to Facebook.

Comment: Ok, but did you test your URL in OG debug tool?

Comment: Hi I did and it comes out fine. I have just noticed now that some likes are comign through fine, some are not. The plot thickens...

Comment: Ok most are not - it is very inconsistent.